# On the usage of "epitomized"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, word-usage, past-participles

> Epitomized by right captainship, the ship reached safely to the harbor.

I'm emphasizing the capabilities of the captain here. Is this correct usage?

Comment: I think this is *not* a valid usage of *epitomise*.

Comment: Once you work out *epitomized*, find out the correct usage of *right*.

Comment: How about this usage? "Under epitomised captainship, the ship reached safely to the harbor"

Comment: +1 Though I think you stated the question end-to-beginning or somewhat counter-intuitively.

Answer (score 6):

Things epitomise qualities.

> Epitomising sound captainship, the ship reached safety.

Better still:

> He epitomised sound captainship, and brought the ship to safety.

Since ships don't really have captainship, it's a quality of the captain rather than the ship.

Comment: Absolutely. Only people (or maybe things like "recommended procedures" - certainly not "ships") can "epitomise" any kind of captainship. And "sound" is by far the best word for "good" captainship ("right" here is completely "wrong").

Comment: +1 The first is what the OP meant to say and should have said. The second sentence does not mean the same thing and is not an option.

Comment: @Kris: In my language, ships can't show captainship, far less epitomise it, so the first is simply wrong.  The second is possible: the fact that it doesn't mean the same as the first is if anything in its favour.

Comment: @Kris, the first is grammatically correct, the second is grammatically correct and not nonsense. A ship could only possibly epitomise captainship in the sort of cartoons like "Cars" and "Thomas the Tank Engine" where vehicles are sentient and hence capable of having such qualities.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be "epitomized with right captainship", since "right captainship" is the characteristic that the ship has perfected through the captain, the ship's epitome.